# JS: Why "Strict Mode " is not showing Reference Error while declaring a variable without var while keeping function and variable name same

Tags: javascript

Why the second code runs and further doesn't show reference error?

The first code where function name and variable name are different:

```js
function foo() {
  "use strict";
  a = 1;
  console.log(a);
}
foo();
```

Source: You Don't Know Js

The above first code throws an error as:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

The second code where function name and variable name are "Same"

```js
function a() {
  "use strict";
  a = 1;
  console.log(a);
}
a();
```

The above second code runs and throws an output "1".

Comment: Because a is defined in the second one.

Comment: `a` is a defined symbol in the same scope (it was originally a function)

Comment: It would be even more obvious if you had written `const foo = function() {…` and `const a = function() {…`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just to ilustrate**

The first example it's very clear, for `'use strict';` (aka ["strict mode"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)) you need to use the `var` (or `let` or `const`) to declare a variable.

---

The second example it's a little tricky because the function `a` is declared in your context as a available variable.

**The following code is similar to the second example:**

```
var a = function() {
  "use strict";
  a = 1;
  console.log(a);
};
```

So, `a` was declared and it's valid for `user strict` mode.

```js
function a() {
  "use strict";
  a = 1;
  console.log(a);
}

//If you prints the variable 'a' (function in this case) look what it prints:
console.log(a);

a();

//After that execution, if you prints the variable 'a' (commom variable) look what it prints:
console.log("Now variable 'a' is a integer variable: " + a);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second example `a` is defined in the outer scope by the function declaration. The assignment inside the function modifies that outer value. If you were to call `a()` *again* it would result in an error, because the first invocation replaced the function that was bound to `a` with `1`.

```
function a() {
  "use strict";
  a = 1;
  console.log(a);
}
a();
a();
```

That will print `1` but then throw `TypeError: a is not a function` on the second invocation.